# Javascript onchange não funciona para combox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mvc

Tenho um uma function no javascript que funciona perfeitamente para um textbox

```
$('#Year').on('change', function () {
    alert("test"); 
});
```

Porém, para um combobox, ela não funciona

```
$('#EntityId').on('change', function () {
    alert("test"); 
});
```

Tentei usar `.change(function (){})` mas também não funciona

Comment: O erro deve estar no HTML. O `id` deve estar diferente, duplicado ou  malformado.

Answer (score 2):

Use o binder `.change` do jQuery que funciona perfeitamente, embora eles faça a mesma coisa que o teu código segundo a documentação:

> As the .change() method is just a shorthand for .on( "change", handler
>   ), detaching is possible using .off( "change" ).

Ou seja, uma "forma abreviada" para o `on("change")`

Leia mais aqui: https://api.jquery.com/change/

```js
$('#EntityId').change(function () {
    alert("test"); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="EntityId">
  <option>-- selecione --</option>
  <option>2020</option>
  <option>2019</option>
  <option>2018</option>
</select>
```